# Image Name Not Save In Database in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi friends in my code image upload in my folder but it's not saved in database am not knowledge about CI so help me for this

view code for upload image,

```
<form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <fieldset class="form-group">                                            
       <input type="hidden" name="txt_hidden" value="" class="form-control"> 
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="formGroupExampleInput">Add Main Caregory</label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('p_name'); ?>" placeholder="Main Category" name="p_name" class="form-control"> 
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label"  for="formGroupExampleInput2">Order</label>
         <input type="text" name="order_id" placeholder="Order Id" value="<?php echo set_value('order_id'); ?>" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2"> 
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label"  for="formGroupExampleInput2">Status ( 0 active , 1 inactive)</label>
         <input type="text" name="status" placeholder="Status" value="<?php echo set_value('status'); ?>" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2"> 
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label"  for="formGroupExampleInput2">Image</label>
          <input type="file" name="image" placeholder="Category Image" value="<?php echo set_value('image'); ?>" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2">
   </fieldset>                                              

   <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Category</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

in My controller

use this for add category with an image

```
function add_main_category()
{

 $this->form_validation->set_rules('p_name', 'Main Category', 'required|is_unique[main_category.p_name]');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('order_id', 'Order Id');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'Category Image', 'callback_cat_image_upload');

      if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
      {
           $this->load->view('master/add_main_category');
      }
      else
      {
           $p_name = strtolower($this->input->post('p_name'));
           $order_id = strtolower($this->input->post('order_id'));
           $status = strtolower($this->input->post('status'));
           $image = strtolower($this->input->post('image'));
           $data = array(
                        'p_name' => $p_name,
                        'order_id' => $order_id,
                        'status' => $status,
                        'image' => $image
                  );
           $insert = $this->m->CategoryAdd($data);
           if($insert){
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg','Category Created Successfully!!');
            }
            else{
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'Failed to delete Category');
            }
            redirect('admin/main_cat');

       }
}
```

and for image upload use this in controller

```
function cat_image_upload(){
  if($_FILES['image']['size'] != 0){
    $upload_dir = './uploads/';
    if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
         mkdir($upload_dir);
    }   
    $config['upload_path']   = $upload_dir;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['file_name']     = 'userimage_'.substr(md5(rand()),0,7);
    $config['overwrite']     = false;
    $config['max_size']  = '5120';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')){
        $this->form_validation->set_message('cat_image_upload', $this->upload->display_errors());
        return false;
    }   
    else{
        $this->upload_data['file'] =  $this->upload->data();
        return true;
    }   
}   
else{
    $this->form_validation->set_message('cat_image_upload', "No file selected");
    return false;
}
```

}

table main_category in column image

everything is working only no image name save in database!

help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean everything is working? There must be something not working or else we wouldn't be here :) Try to explain the problem you are having, and also please indent your code properly.

Comment: @Dev4World means code is working insert data in other column except image and image upload in folder i just want to save image name in database thats it

Answer (score 0):

You can't store the image in the way you used as:

```
$image = strtolower($this->input->post('image'));
```

Get the image file name once it is uploaded. Here is your modified code:

```
 if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')){
    $this->form_validation->set_message('cat_image_upload', $this->upload->display_errors());
    return false;
}   
else{
    $this->upload_data['file'] =  $this->upload->data();
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $doc_file_name = $data['upload_data']['file_name']; // Use this file name to store in database
    return true;
}
```

Comment: sir can tell me how to get image name , i used your code in upload image controller and via this image upload in folder but cant understand from where insert image name in database ??

Comment: <code>$p_name = strtolower($this->input->post('p_name'));
                $order_id = strtolower($this->input->post('order_id'));
                $status = strtolower($this->input->post('status'));
                $doc_file_name = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
                $data = array(
                        'p_name' => $p_name,
                        'order_id' => $order_id,
                        'status' => $status,
                        'image' => $doc_file_name
                ); <code>do this but still not work

Comment: Try to use the functionality of cat_image_upload() inside your else statment